# I have a button with background image. How to trigger a mouseleave event with a certain condition?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button with a background. I created mouseenter & mouseleave event. In the mouseleave event, if a mouse cursor is outside of 2 coordinates it will trigger the mouseleave event.

```
private void Button_SpanMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button x = sender as Button;
        x.Size = new Size(500, 250);
        x.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    private void Button_SpanMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button x = sender as Button;

        //If cursor is outside of this coordinates(0,0) & (250,125)
        //it will trigger this size
        x.Size = new Size(250,125);
        x.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
```

my problem is when i leave in 500X250 rectangle, it will trigger the mouseleave. i want it to trigger in 250X125 rectangle.

Comment: You can handle the MouseLeave and return if not in the expected boundaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To archieve the effect you are trying, instead of the `Button_MouseLeave` Event you'll need to use the `MouseMove` Event. So remove your `Button_SpanMouseLeave` event and add this one:

```
private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button x = sender as Button;
    Point p = PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition);
    if (p.X > 250|| p.Y >125)
    {
        button1.Size = new Size(250, 125);
        button1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In fact, you don't need the PointToClient Method at all. so the code would be like this:

```
private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button x = sender as Button;
    if (e.X > 250|| e.Y >125)
    {
        x.Size = new Size(250, 125);
        x.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Ok, if the button is not located in `0,0` then it's better to use `PointToClient` like this:

```
private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button x = sender as Button;
    Point p = PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition);
    this.label1.Text = p.X.ToString() + " " + p.Y.ToString();
    if (p.X > x.Location.X + 250 || p.Y > x.Location.Y+125)
    {
        button1.Size = new Size(250, 125);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked in one of my case if the coordinates are P(0,0) to P(250,125). what if the coordinates will be from P(100,200) to P(350,325)

Comment: thanks. But the mousemove trigger if the cursor is in right&bottom side of the button. it will not execute if the cursor is above&left side of a button. to be clear, it is not trigger if 0≤x≤100 & 0≤y≤200.